# Conditional in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Can someone please show me how to preform the following in pandas:

if 
value in dataframeA'columnX' = value in dataframeB'columnX' then print value in dataframeB'columnY'

I've tried the following without sucess:

```
DATABASE = np.where(PMAGRESULT['ROCKUNITNO'] == ROCKUNIT['ROCKUNITNO'], PMAGRESULT['PLAT'])
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually just want to print the values in dataframeB['columnY'] (and no need to store them for later) or do you want, for example, a Series that you can print.

Comment: Do df1 and df2 have the same index? If so, you can just do `print(df2.loc[df2.colx == df1.colx, 'coly'])`

Comment: Are you asking to perform what Excel calls a VLOOKUP inside of pandas?

Comment: @jedwards I would like to store the values.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi df1 and df2 do not have the same index. PMAGRESULT has 9258 rows and ROCKUNIT has 7513

Comment: @ThePoetCoder, I'm not very familiar with VLOOKUP, but after a quick google search it looks like a function similar to what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ROCKUNIT => dfA and PMAGRESULT => dfB;

If the indices do not align, consider using a merge:

```
PMAGRESULT.merge(ROCKUNIT['ROCKUNITNO'], on='ROCKUNITNO')['PLAT']
```

Otherwise, if the lengths (and indexes) are the same, you can perform an equality check:

```
PMAGRESULT.loc[
   PMAGRESULT['ROCKUNITNO'] == ROCKUNIT['ROCKUNITNO'],
   'PLAT'
]
```